# What is my Xpath expression resulting in "$content-type": "application/xml;charset=utf-8" "$content": "PGNvbXBhc3NpZD4xMjI1NDI8L2NvbXBhc3NpZD4="

Tags: xml, xpath, power-automate

I am using MS Flow and have an HTTP request giving me the following XML content from a query:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<qdbapi>
    <action>API_DoQuery</action>
    <errcode>0</errcode>
    <errtext>No error</errtext>
<dbinfo>
<name>Won Opportunities</name>
<desc></desc>
</dbinfo>
<variables>
</variables>
<chdbids>
</chdbids>
  <record>
<compassid>122542</compassid>
    <update_id>1597844618723</update_id>
  </record>
  <record>
<compassid>222222</compassid>
    <update_id>1597844607031</update_id>
  </record>
  <record>
<compassid>981344</compassid>
    <update_id>1597840564426</update_id>
  </record>
</qdbapi>
```

I need an xpath expression that makes an array from the values in  tags. So 981344, 222222, 122542.

Current xpath expression is

```
 xpath(xml(body('CompassIDs')),'/qdbapi/record/compassid')
```

I get the result:

```
[
  {
    "$content-type": "application/xml;charset=utf-8",
    "$content": "PGNvbXBhc3NpZD4xMjI1NDI8L2NvbXBhc3NpZD4="
  },
  {
    "$content-type": "application/xml;charset=utf-8",
    "$content": "PGNvbXBhc3NpZD4yMjIyMjI8L2NvbXBhc3NpZD4="
  },
  {
    "$content-type": "application/xml;charset=utf-8",
    "$content": "PGNvbXBhc3NpZD45ODEzNDQ8L2NvbXBhc3NpZD4="
  }
]
```

Please help! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your xpath is returning the node objects instead of their values. As a result you are getting the object base64 encoded. So, for instance, `PGNvbXBhc3NpZD4xMjI1NDI8L2NvbXBhc3NpZD4=` is equivalent to `<compassid>122542</compassid>` when decoded

You need to change your xpath from `/qdbapi/record/compassid` to `/qdbapi/record/compassid/text()` which will give you the value of the element text, ie. 122542 in this case