# getting first node of xml in logicapps

Tags: xpath, azure-logic-apps

I need to have first node of below xml that is inside of FIToFICstmrCdtTrf. However, xpath returns binary data.

```
xpath(xml(triggerBody()),'/')
xpath(xml(triggerBody())x,'/FIToFICstmrCdtTrf')
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.02">
    <FIToFICstmrCdtTrf>
        <GrpHdr>
            <MsgId>x</MsgId>
            <CreDtTm>x</CreDtTm>
            <NbOfTxs>2</NbOfTxs>
            ....
```

Comment: Do you mean that xpath returns base64 encoded data? In that case you can just use the base64ToString() logic app function.

Answer (score 2):

Your XML is bound to the namespace `urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.02`, so unless you register the namespace in order to be able to use a namespace-prefix in your XPath, you need to address the elements by their `local-name()`.

For instance: `/*[local-name()="Document"]/*[local-name()="FIToFICstmrCdtTrf"]`

and then to select the first child element (`GrpHdr`), you can append a generic expression selecting any element `*` and apply a predicate filter to select the first: `/*[1]`

Putting it all together:

```
xpath(xml(triggerBody()),
  '/*[local-name()="Document"]/*[local-name()="FIToFICstmrCdtTrf"]/*[1]')
```

Comment: It returns binary data taht is [{"$content-type":"application/xml;charset=utf-8","$content":"PEdycEhkciB4bWxucz0idXJ..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63496200/14419

Comment: I got empty string with below xpath:                                      
xpath(xml(triggerBody()),'/*[local-name()="Document"]/*[local-name()="FIToFICstmrCdtTrf"]/text()')                                                                           
                                                                                                                                        
["\n        ","\n        ","\n        ","\n        ","\n        ","\n    "]

Comment: `/*[local-name()="Document"]/*[local-name()="FIToFICstmrCdtTrf"]/text()` will return the _text nodes_ which are children of the `FIToFICstmrCdtTrf` element. That's what the `text()` node test does; it identifies text nodes. Those text nodes are line breaks and spaces between each of the child elements of the `FIToFICstmrCdtTrf` element. What is it that you _actually_ want to retrieve?

Answer (score 1):

After reproducing from my end, I was able to get this working by applying the below expressions in the flow of my logic app:

```
xpath(xml(variables('XML')),'/*[local-name()="Document"]/*[local-name()="FIToFICstmrCdtTrf"]/*')?[0]
```

*OR*

```
xpath(xml(variables('XML')),'/*[name()="Document"]/*[name()="FIToFICstmrCdtTrf"]/*')?[0]
```

Below is the flow of my logic app

[image]

*RESULTS:*

[image]